# Android: decrypt AES with 128 bit key size and 128 bit block size - Block cipher mode: CBC-CS1

Tags: java, android, cryptography, aes, cbc-mode

I need to decrypt some data (on Android) that is encrypted with the following specs:

- AES with 128 bit key size and 128 bit block size
- Block cipher mode: CBC-CS1 (CBC with ciphertext stealing, variant 1, as specified in [CBCCS])

Didn't find much information on Internet and all the AES decryption methods I've tried so far don't work.

The main problem seem to be the implementation of CBC-CS1, is it supported or should I implement myself?

Thanks,
Dem

Comment: BouncyCastle provides the [CTSBlockCipher](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.52/org/bouncycastle/crypto/modes/CTSBlockCipher.java#CTSBlockCipher) so you should be able to use it.

Comment: From WikiPedia: "The numbering here is taken from Dworkin, who describes them all. The third is the most popular, and described by Daemen and Schneier; Meyer describes a related, but incompatible scheme (with respect to bit ordering and key use)." So it seems you should be able to use `CTSBlockCipher`, but only after swapping the last and first to last (partial) block.

Comment: AES only has a 128-bit block size.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you should be able to use `new NISTCTSBlockCipher(NISTCTSBlockCipher.CS1, aes)` if you want. One thing is probably making a difference: you should directly feed it the AES block cipher, e.g.:

```
AESFastEngine aes = new AESFastEngine();
NISTCTSBlockCipher aescbccts = new NISTCTSBlockCipher(NISTCTSBlockCipher.CS1, aes);
```

which is different from `CTSBlockCipher` which seems to expect `CBCBlockCipher` (for CBC + CTS operation anyway).

If you do feed it CBC then you - funny enough - end up with double CBC = ECB again:

```
CTB_n = E(CTB_n-1 XOR CTB_n-1 XOR PTB_n) = E(PTB_n).
```

---

From WikiPedia:

> The numbering here is taken from Dworkin, who describes them all. The third is the most popular, and described by Daemen and Schneier; Meyer describes a related, but incompatible scheme (with respect to bit ordering and key use).

I just verified that Bouncy implements CS3. So it seems you should be able to use `CTSBlockCipher` (as ArtjomB suggests), but only after swapping the (partial) last and first to last block.

Alternatively you may simply rewrite the `CTSBlockCipher`, Bouncy Castle has a very permissive license.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what about `NISTCTSBlockCipher`? it seems to implement CS1, 2 and 3 but it seems I'm not getting the correct data anyway...

Comment: Ah, I'll have a look! Sorry, sometimes missing out on this kind of functionality is easy, especially with Bouncy with the uber large collection of algorithms & modes.

Comment: I've manually verified the CS1, CS2 and CS3 operation and it looks OK at first sight.

Comment: Thanks, I'll double check my code then, will write for an update